# MicroLite and Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, micro-orm

Are there any known issues when using MicroLite on Azure SQL Database?

We encounter some strange behaviors that are a bit disturbing. When auditing the database, we monitor that our queries are handled by the server in a very good way (50ns). However, the "rpc completed" events arrive in times that are thousands times the delay they should be (500000ns). We do not have such issues when using Entity Framework on this server.

Comment: A micro-orm. Please Google it... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was identified, but many questions remain. I opened another thread here : [Why does Azure Database perform better with transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231430/why-does-azure-database-perform-better-with-transactions)